# Transparent streamlines in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to use a **streamline** plot similar to the one below. Because there is other visual data in the plot involved I want to modify the transparency of the streamlines. Is it possible to tweak the alpha of the single lines or the whole plot (as I merge multiple sequential plots with switch 'hold on')?

[image: streamlines]

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to turn the lines into patches.

alternativly you could render an image from your plot. And then overlay the image to your other plot. The image can have alpha.